# Using OpenRefine API with python3 and requests module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, openrefine

I am trying the use the [OpenRefine API](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/OpenRefine-API) making a request to create a project (similar to [this implementation](https://github.com/maxogden/refine-python/blob/master/refine.py#L12) but with python3)

What I have tried so far is:

```
data = {
     "project-name":"toto",
     "project-file": {
          "fd": open(project_file, "rb"),
           "filename": project_file,
     }
}
response = requests.post(self.server + '/command/core/create-project-from-upload', data=data)
```

I have also tried using the `files` argument of `requests`:

```
data = {"project-name":"toto"}
files = {'project-file': (project_file, open(project_file, "rb"))}
response = requests.post(self.server + '/command/core/create-project-from-upload', data=data, files=files)
```

In both cases, I receive a 200 response but not providing the project ID as expected from the doc but a HTML body:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--

Copyright 2010, Google Inc.
All rights reserved.

 [...]

<body>
<div id="header">
  <a id="app-home-button" href="./"><img alt="OpenRefine" src="images/logo-openrefine-30.png" width="129" height="29" /></a>
  <div id="project-title">
    <span id="project-name-button" class="app-path-section"></span>
    <a id="project-permalink-button" href="javascript:{}" class="secondary"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="project-controls">
    <a href="./" class="button" target="_blank"><span id="or-proj-open"></span></a>
    <a class="button" bind="exportButton" id="export-button" href="#export"><span class="button-menu" id="or-proj-export"></span></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Documentation-For-Users" target="_blank" class="button"><span id="or-proj-help"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="loading-message"><img src="images/large-spinner.gif" /> <span id="or-proj-starting"></span></div>

<div id="body">
  <div bind="leftPanelDiv" id="left-panel">
    <div bind="leftPanelTabs" class="refine-tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#refine-tabs-facets" id="or-proj-facFil"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#refine-tabs-history" bind="historyTabHeader" id="or-proj-undoRedo"></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="refine-tabs-facets" bind="facetPanelDiv" id="facet-panel"></div>
      <div id="refine-tabs-history" bind="historyPanelDiv" id="history-panel"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div bind="rightPanelDiv" id="right-panel">
    <div bind="toolPanelDiv" id="tool-panel">
      <div bind="summaryBarDiv" id="summary-bar">
        <!-- row/record counts -->
      </div>
      <div bind="extensionBarDiv" id="extension-bar">
        <span id="or-proj-ext"></span> <span bind="menuContainer" id="extension-bar-menu-container"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div bind="viewPanelDiv" id="view-panel"></div>
  </div>
  <div bind="processPanelDiv" id="notification-container"></div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Following comment by @nlsdfnbch, seems the parameter I need to get is contained in :

```
In [15]: response.request.url
Out[15]: 'http://127.0.0.1:3333/project?project=1533970971677'
```

**What is going on?** Why is the result available here and not in the response  object?

Comment: have you checked that the URL is correct? You can access it via `response.request.url`. Seems like the address exists but it isn't what you actually want to access (hence the html, instead of JSON)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I can get closer to the result, even if not understanding why yet....

Comment: Have you explored the rest of the `Response` object? You can find its attributes [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response)

Comment: Oh, ok, so looking at `history`, it seems my request is redirected to the new URL. Not really obvious from the doc... 

Thanks for the help @nlsdfnbch !